# Hello, how i can test a const function in jest enzyme? inside a component

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm traying to test a full component and there are a const function inside, so for example if i have a
`const function(val1){  }` and inside of my function i have called an api

i guess in my test in jest i would try to make this

```
spyOn(mycomponent, 'function').mockImplementationOnce(()=> {return Promise.resolve(EvaluationsMock)})
const wrapper = mount(<mycomponent/>)
```

Comment: You can't. Assert or mock side effects it causes.

Comment: so, how i cant test this part ? or may there are restriction for jest

Comment: You can't access local variables outside a scope where they were defined, which is component function in this case. This is the restriction of JS.

Comment: Okey  thanks, everyday you learn something new.

Comment: FWIW, React Testing Library is more suitable for testing functional components than Enzyme because there's no component instance to access, the former doesn't rely on it.